# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'function'

Tags: python, function

I just started programming in python and i made this little program which sums the total price of n things you've bought.
Then it sums the total price of n things you've sold and returns what you
earned. So it seems i made some confusion with functions, but i can't find the mistake, could someone help me? (sorry for my english)
This is the output:

```
Type 'earn' to see if you earned something
Type 'quit' to exit
Type here: earn
BOUGHT
Things you've bought: 3
SOLD
Things you've sold: 3
EARN
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/daze/Documents/earn.py", line 52, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/daze/Documents/earn.py", line 11, in main
earn()
File "/Users/daze/Documents/earn.py", line 50, in earn
return sell_sum - buy_sum
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'function'
```

and this is the complete code:

```
def main():
print("Type 'earn' to see if you earned something")
print("Type 'quit' to exit")
choice_menu = input("Type here: ")
if choice_menu == 'earn':
    print("BOUGHT")
    buy_sum()
    print("SOLD")
    sell_sum()
    print("EARN")
    earn()
    yes_or_no()
elif choice_menu == 'quit':
    print("Quitting..")
else:
    print("Wrong key!")
    main()
def yes_or_no():
    choice_continue = None
    while choice_continue != 'y' or choice_continue != 'n':
        choice_continue = input("Do you want to continue?(y/n)")
        print("Insert a valid key!")
    if choice_continue == 'y':
        main()
    else:
        print("Quitting..")
def buy_sum():
    n_buy = eval(input("Things you've bought: "))
    buy_sum = 0
    cont = 1
    price_buy = 0
    while cont <= n_buy and price_buy < 0:
        price_buy = eval(input("Price ", str(cont), ": "))
        buy_sum = buy_sum + price_buy
        print("Actual shipment:", buy_sum)
        cont = cont + 1
    return buy_sum
def sell_sum():
    n_sell = eval(input("Things you've sold: "))
    sell_sum = 0
    cont = 1
    price_sell = 0
    while cont <= n_sell and price_sell < 0:
        price_sell = eval(input("Price ", str(cont), ": "))
        sell_sum = sell_sum + price_sell
        print("Actual sold:", buy_sum)
        cont = cont + 1
    return sell_sum
def earn():
    return sell_sum - buy_sum

main()
```

Just tell me why it gives me that error and where i made a mistake, if there are error in whiles or other things like don't correct me, just make me notice that.
thank you.

Comment: `return sell_sum - buy_sum` should be `return sell_sum() - buy_sum()`. Also there's no `eval()` needed, use `int()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the functions in the final line to get the result

```
def earn():
    return sell_sum() - buy_sum()
```

Also, it's a bad idea it call main() at the end of the main function.  I bet you will never run into a problem with this code, but it just keeps adding stack frames onto the stack which would eventually overflow.